# custom user model making the emails unique but not case sensetive?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

so I have a custom user model to make the users sign up/in using emails instead of a username the problem is I grab the email as it's entered in the form and save and my model is assigning this field to be `unique` so it's case sensitive.

so you see the problem if a user entered the email uppercase he can't log in till he enters the email similar to that of the signup page.

my model

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username =         None
    email =            models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

the form

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model =     MyUser
        fields =    ('email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

and this is the view to send confirmation emails to the users

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your Sentizer account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        subject=mail_subject, body=message, to=[to_email], reply_to=[to_email],headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
            )
            email.send(fail_silently=False)
            messages.info(request,"Please confirm your email to be able to login")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('accounts:login'))
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

and thanks for ur help.

Comment: Do you want to save the email as a case sensitive value or is converting it to lowercase an option?

Comment: converting it to lowercase seems convenient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If converting the email address to lowercase is convenient for you, you could just do that. So in your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    user.is_active = False
    user.email = form.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
    user.save()
    # ...
```

If you do that you have to make sure that on logging in the email address entered by the user in your signup form is converted to lowercase to, of course.